# Azure will not turn off custom errors

Tags: asp.net, azure, configuration, web-config

I'm in the process of migrating a client site to an Azure VM (stop gap until we rewrite to move to Azure Proper). The problem that I have is that there is a problem somewhere and I can't see what it is. When I run up the site I get the usual yellow screen of death...

> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>   It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server
>   machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

I have had this many times before in such situations, so I edited the web.config file to look like this...

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    (other stuff)
</system.web>
```

... and the same message came up. I recycled the app pool and even restarted IIS but I still get the same message, it's as if the VM just doesn't care what I put in the config file.

I've added 'localhost' to the bindings so I can view it on the server directly and I get this instead...

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file:
>   Directory 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.siansplan.com\config' does not
>   exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.siansplan.com\web.config    Line:
>   0
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18447

Has anyone else come up against this before?

I'm at a loss what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this one. The web.config file was referencing a child file which wasn't present. This is quite a gotcha if you can't use localhost based debugging.

Comment: Glad you found the answer.

Comment: what does it look like to reference a child file? I cannot get my customErrors to work

Answer (score 1):

Your system.web tag is not properly closed:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    (other stuff)
</ system.web>
```

Should be:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    (other stuff)
</system.web>
```

Comment: Sorry - that was a typo on my behalf (now corrected) The actual answer was due to a missing child file. It amounts to kind of the same thing, when the core web.config file has an error you don't get the message. I would assume that, had the file been as above, you would probably have exactly the same symptoms.